# Nintendo DSi SD card

Tags: nintendo-dsi

I'm a little bit confused - I see ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00266P7KY) for example) special Nintendo DSi SDHC cards.

My question is if there is really any difference between these NDSi cards and a regular SDHC cards? Can I use a regular card and if I do, will I be limited in any aspect compared to a NDSi card?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like it on the surface ;)

Comment: @ChrisF - What doesn't look like it?

Comment: That there's any difference between a "normal" HCSD card and a Ninetendo branded one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nintendo DSi and DSi XL accepts any SD or SDHC memory card up to 32GB in size.

The Wii also accepts any SD or SDHC memory cards, although you need firmware 4.0 or newer for SDHC to be recognized.

[Source](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/dsi/en_na/sdCards.jsp#compatible_sd)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just wonder what is it with the "Nintendo DSi" cards? Just a sales accelerator thing?

Comment: @ysap: They think they can make money by selling Nintendo-branded cards, so they do!